# WPF Trigger and Binding problem

Tags: wpf, data-binding, triggers, styles

I am creating a button with a simple Polyline which I want to change color when the button is Disabled (`btnUp.IsEnabled = false`).

I tried this:

```
<RepeatButton x:Name="btnUp" Foreground="Green">
  <RepeatButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
      <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Polyline x:Name="arrowUp" Points="0,2 3,0 6,2" Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RepeatButton}, Path=Foreground, Mode=TwoWay}" StrokeThickness="2"/>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </RepeatButton.Style>
</RepeatButton>
```

But the Polyline still has the same (Green) color when the button is disabled. Even though I did expect it to be white because of the databinding between the button.foreground and polyline.stroke.

However if I change the trigger to this it works (the button is collapsed):

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on my own.
I moved the `Foreground="Green"` to a separate setter, `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF383838"/>` inside the `<Style>`, then it worked.
I'm not sure why though.

Here's the complete solution:

```
<RepeatButton x:Name="btnUp">
  <RepeatButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
      <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
          <Polyline x:Name="arrowUp" Points="0,2 3,0 6,2" Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RepeatButton}, Path=Foreground, Mode=TwoWay}" StrokeThickness="2"/>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </RepeatButton.Style>
</RepeatButton>
```

Comment: Explicit property values are higher-priority than trigger values, which are higher-priority than style values -- so your fix is exactly correct. For more background, read the "Dependency Property Setting Precedence List" section of: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx